# how to wait untill chain of asyc calls is succeeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await

I have a function which is making an async call
and upon sucess, its making another async call

ex:-

```
    function1 = () => {
      /*Some required Logic*/
  return fetch("myurl")
      .then((json) => {
        function2(json)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
}

function2 = () => {
  /*Some required Logic*/
  return fetch("myurl2")
      .then((json) => {
        callthirdfunction(json)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
}
```

now here is the function 3
in which i am dependent on the success of function1

```
function3 = () => {
  /*Some required Logic*/
  function1().then(() => {
})
}
```

Issue is it is only waiting untill the function1's asyc call is succeeded its not waiting for function2's async call to succeed

I know i can write like chain of asyn call but its not possible because of unavoidable circumstances

Any suggesstion or leads in this regard would be of great help

Comment: You want function3 to fire once function1 and function2 are done?

Comment: my code flow is like this from function3, i am making function1 call and function 1 call is dependent on function2. So, once both function1 and function2 succeeded i want to have my logic.
makes sense?

Comment: Your problem is that you don't `return` the promises you use from the `then` callbacks, so the promise chain cannot know what to wait for.

Comment: @Bergi, i am making use of return. updated my question. please have a look

Comment: @user3677291 The callbacks themselves still don't `return` the promises that `function2` (now) returns

Answer (score 0):

If you used `async await` as you mentioned in your tags, you could just use it like that:

```
await function1();
await function2();
await function3();
```

while adding the `async` keyword to the function declarations:

```
function1 = async () => {

}
```

Another option is to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736705/how-to-promisify-this-function-nodejs) your functions, and then call them like that:

```
function1()
.then(function2)
.then(function3)
.catch() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one promise to depend on another promise, you need to `return` the dependent promise from `then`.

Your code doesn't *do* anything with the result of `function2`:

```
return fetch("myurl")
  .then((json) => {
    function2(json)

  })
```

That should read

```
.then((json) => {
  return function2(json)
})
```

The whole point of `then` is that it allows chaining of subsequent promises by returning them from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Promises get chained only if you return them. In the below example

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}


async function add1(x) {
  const a = await resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
  const b = await resolveAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + a + b;
}
```

Notice the return keyword inside resolveAfter2Seconds. Make sure that when you call a method that fires a promise, you add the 'return' keyword