# sync function that await an event (once more

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Desperately trying to write a sync version of https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firebird#reading-blobs-aasynchronous

Basically I need to (a)wait twice:

1. for the callback function to execute so that the eventEmitter is available
2. for the "end" event to occur

and then return the Buffer.

my code (JS/TS mix for now) currently does 2, but not 1 : readBlob returns undefined, then Buffer.concat(buffers) is called later ... :

```
function readBLOB(callback: any): Buffer {
    return  callback(async (err, _, eventEmitter) => {
        let buffers = []
        if (err)
            throw err

        eventEmitter.on('data', chunk => {
            buffers.push(chunk);
        });
        return await eventEmitter.once('end', function (e) {
            return Buffer.concat(buffers)
        })
    })
}
```

Sorry to ask one more time (yes, I checked a lot of other questions and tried a lot of things...), but how to make this work (simply...) ?

(the function that calls the callback is fetch_blob_async in https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird/blob/master/lib/index.js#L4261 , just in case...)

Comment: You can't make an async function execution sync how much you ever wanted to. It's just simply not possible. You've to adapt "asynchronous thinking", and design your code to make a benefit of asynchronicity instead of keeping stuck in synchronous design.

Comment: You can, however, make it return a Promise which resolves to a Buffer, if that suits you (still async, but you can `const buf = await readBlob()`) Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34736837/1913729) which transforms a callback function into one that returns a Promise

Comment: ok.. you said you want to await an event once more.. so the `asyncLoop` would go over until what you define as a `success` or a `fail`

Comment: @Teemu, you're right. Most of my code is async, based on StencilJS (or rather TS) web components and a node express server. My "only" problem is : how to send  res.status(200).json(rows||{}) when rows contain some BLOB fields that are returned async by the node-firebird package ? at this point I need all the content of rows to be sync in order to be sent...

Answer (score 2):

There are few mistakes here like returning an callback function, witch returns, i guess, `undefined` or returning something IN an callback function that makes no sense.

Also `async / await` makes no sense here it has no effect. `async / await` is only useful if you want to await till some Promise resolves. But you have no Promise in your code at all.

What you need is `new Promise`

```
function readBLOB(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    callback((err, _, eventEmitter) => {
      let buffers = [];
      if (err) reject(err);
      eventEmitter.on("data", chunk => {
        buffers.push(chunk);
      });
      eventEmitter.once("end", function(e) {
        resolve(Buffer.concat(buffers));
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Simple like that. You `resolve` your Buffer and `reject` if some error occurs

Now you can use it like:

```
readBLOB(cb).then(data => {
   console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Don't forget to put the stuff using `eventEmitter` in an `else` block or you'll get uncaught exceptions

Comment: thanks, but I precisely do not want to use readBLOB(cb).then ... I want to obtain to use it as  let blob:Buffer = readBLOB(cb)

Comment: @Dr.Goulu well thats not possible i guess